# WOPI discovery synchronization failed in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, owa, oos

WOPI discovery synchronization failed in SharePoint 2016

We are facing Proof key sync issue in our environment. After investigating, encountering the below error.

"the validation of proof token is failed and possible cause is that the issuer of the proof token is not trusted or proof token has invalid claims in it"

[image]

Can you please help me how to resolve this Timer job issue

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps below to troubleshoot your issue:

1. clear SharePoint config cache and do IISRESET.
2. Update the proof key by PowerShell command “Update-SPWOPIProofKey”.
3. If the issue exists, try to rebuild the binding using PowerShell command as below:

   `Remove-SPWOPIBinding –All:$true
    New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName <ServerName> -AllowHTTP`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check ULS logs and get more clue, in most of the cases it is due to certificate validation failed.

- Check the ULS logs,when the timer jobs run, you will see what error being reported.
- Clear the Configuration cache most of the case fix the issue. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68a02bcc-3f94-407d-9fa0-17c72ff8d62b/wopi-discovery-synchronization-failing-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=OfficeOnlineServer
- Check this one, may be related to the proof key. http://itgroove.net/mmman/2015/03/15/what-to-do-if-office-web-apps-owa-stops-working-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Its working for me. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I had this job failing after connecting my SharePoint 2016 to a different OOS and got it resolved by only clearing the config cache on every server in my SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt OWA server with HTTPS on pre-existing 2013 farm, got this error. Resolution was to clear config cache on all servers.